# Is uninitialized local variable the fastest random number generator?

Tags: c++, c, undefined-behavior, garbage

I know the uninitialized local variable is undefined behaviour(*UB*), and also the value may have trap representations which may affect further operation, but sometimes I want to use the random number only for visual representation and will not further use them in other part of program, for example, set something with random color in a visual effect, for example:

```
void updateEffect(){
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
        int r;
        int g;
        int b;
        star[i].setColor(r%255,g%255,b%255);
        bool isVisible;
        star[i].setVisible(isVisible);
    }
}
```

is it that faster than

```
void updateEffect(){
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
        star[i].setColor(rand()%255,rand()%255,rand()%255);
        star[i].setVisible(rand()%2==0?true:false);
    }
}
```

and also faster than other random number generator?

Comment: +1 This is a perfectly legitimate question. It's true that in practice, uninitialized values _might_ be kindof random. The fact that they aren't particularly and that it's UB doesn't make _asking_ that bad.

Comment: @imallett: Absolutely. This is a good question, and at least one old Z80 (Amstrad / ZX Spectrum) game in times past used its *program* as the data to set up its terrain. So there are even precedents. Can't do that these days. Modern operating systems take away all the fun.

Comment: @Bathsheba not necessarily! You can allocate memory with system-specific calls, write data into it, and then execute it. That's how JIT compilers work. There are other possibilities: some systems will even allow you to execute arrays (of bytes corresponding to machine code, for example) with e.g. a `union` and a function pointer.

Comment: Surely the main problem is that it isn't random.

Comment: depends on the quality you are willing to accept in your random number generator.

Comment: @Bathsheba that seems like defined behaviour since the program doesn't change. Unless you're talking about self-modifying code, which was fun...  Actually that reminds me of one funny thing I saw in Z80 code once. There was a `JP` (jump) to halfway through a 2-byte opcode! It turned out that the second byte of the opcode corresponded to a completely different instruction, which was intended to be called.  I'm not sure if an assembler did this or if some imaginative genius came up with it and nobody ever knew...

Comment: In fact, there's an example of a uninitialized variable being used as a random value, see the *Debian RNG disaster* (Example 4 in [this article](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/2066)).

Comment: [some compilers will initialize uninitialized memory with 0xCC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714), so you'll ended up reading the same value every time. In some cases the memory will be zeroed out by the OS after it was used by some other process before this application

Comment: In practice - and believe me, I do a lot of debugging on various architectures - your solution can do two things: either read uninitialized registers or uninitialized memory. Now while "uninitialized" means random in a certain manner, in practice it will most likely contain **a)** _zeroes_, **b)** _repeating or consistent values_ (in case of reading memory formerly occupied by digital media) or **c)** _consistent garbage with a limited value set_ (in case of reading memory formerly occupied by encoded digital data). None of those are real entropy sources.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23415661/1708801) for why using indeterminate values is undefined behavior. Although it is a C++ question in my answer I note references that say the same for C as well.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24296571/1708801) for an example of how the compiler can transform code w/ undefined behavior in unexpected and bad ways.

Comment: @mg30rg or, the compiler can replace any read with `unreachable()` and delete half of your program. This does happen in practice as well. This behavior did completely neutralize the RNG in some Linux distro I believe.

Comment: @usr - I once worked on a platform (a sandboxed c interpreter run on embedded Windows systems) where reading an uninitialized variable led to an access violation exception because it provided a virtual stack instead of a real one and an uninitialized local variable were translated to a nullpointer. Moral of the story - undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: The answer is clearly no, since the uninitialized variable isn't a random number generator at all. Half the time it's a bunch of zeros.

Comment: Even in the absence of optimization, [uninitialized garbage can crash](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/19/60162.aspx).

Comment: @MattMcNabb: A common trick on the 6502 was to use the "BIT abs" opcode $2C as a means of skipping the next two bytes.  A function might have two entry points, three bytes apart: "Entry1: LDA #0 / byte $2C / Entry2: LDA #1 / etc.".  Calling Entry1 will load the accumulator with zero, perform a read from address $01A9 while skipping the LDA #1 instruction, etc.  The Load/Verify entry points in the Commodore VIC-20 Kernel are set up like that.  One slight gotcha is that one must make sure the skipped bytes don't represent an address that could trigger an unwanted behavior when read.

Comment: The Z80 had 7 bit refresh register which was used to help with dram refresh.   It made an adequate seed in most cases.

Comment: Of course there's [an xkcd for this](https://xkcd.com/221/), depicting an equally-fast and much safer implementation (as long as we're still treating "random" and "arbitrary" as the same thing).

Comment: BTW, doing `rand()%n` is generally not a good idea, due to [modulo bias](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10984975/4014959).

Comment: but what if you pick your uninitialized memory randomly?

Comment: @Andy: To do that wouldn't you need a random number generator? :)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError (: it's still not random. some implementations could zero all unallocated memory. Accessing unallocated memory is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882023

Comment: A good way to see how provided numbers are *not* random: get 16-bits "random" numbers a couple of 100-millions times, each time increment the selected number in a 2ˆ16 array, and then observe the numbers distribution. Likely to be disappointing.

Comment: @ring0 Agreed, all the OP had to do was run the code, and then print out the values from the `star` array to see that the values are not the least bit random.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes, overlapping instructions were used deliberately on occasion, as can be seen [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10898). As you can imagine, it was terribly hard to fit everything together, but when you succeeded, you were revered by your peers forevermore :)

Comment: You should select an answer to this question.

Comment: http://kqueue.org/blog/2012/06/25/more-randomness-or-less/

Comment: You should randomly select an answer to this question.  Live the life ergodic.

Answer (score 307):

As others have noted, this is Undefined Behavior (UB).

In practice, it will (probably) actually (kind of) work.  Reading from an uninitialized register on x86[-64] architectures will indeed produce garbage results, and probably won't do anything bad (as opposed to e.g. Itanium, where [registers can be flagged as invalid](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040119-00/?p=41003), so that reads propagate errors like NaN).

There are two main problems though:

1. **It won't be particularly random.**  In this case, you're reading from the stack, so you'll get whatever was there previously.  Which might be effectively random, completely structured, the password you entered ten minutes ago, or your grandmother's cookie recipe.
2. **It's Bad (capital 'B')** practice to let things like this creep into your code.  Technically, the compiler could insert `reformat_hdd();` every time you read an undefined variable.  It *won't*, but you shouldn't do it anyway.  Don't do unsafe things.  The fewer exceptions you make, the safer you are from accidental mistakes *all* the time.

The more pressing issue with UB is that it makes your entire program's behavior undefined.  Modern compilers can use this to elide huge swaths of your code or even [go back in time](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633).  Playing with UB is like a Victorian engineer dismantling a live nuclear reactor.  There's a zillion things to go wrong, and you probably won't know half of the underlying principles or implemented technology.  It *might* be okay, but you still shouldn't let it happen.  Look at the other nice answers for details.

Also, I'd fire you.

Comment: There's no such thing as an "uninitialized register" on any architecture. The machine doesn't understand initialization or lack thereof; it's a language construct.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Itanium registers can contain NaT (Not a Thing) which in effect is an "uninitialized register". On Itanium, reading from a register when you haven't written to it may abort your program (read more on it here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/19/60162.aspx). So there is a good reason why reading uninitialized values is undefined behaviour. It's also probably one reason why Itanium is not very popular :)

Comment: @tbleher Initializing something to a trap representation is not the same as no initialization. Hardware just goes about its business of shuffling bits in a deterministic fashion. But, point taken.

Comment: I really object to the "it kind of works" notion. Even if it was true today, which it is not, it might change at any time due to more aggressive compilers. The compiler can replace any read with `unreachable()` and delete half of your program. This does happen in practice as well. This behavior did completely neutralize the RNG in some Linux distro I believe.; Most answers in this question seem to assume that an uninitialized value behaves like a value at all. That's false.

Comment: *Also, I'd fire you* seems a rather silly thing to say, assuming good practices this should be caught at code review, discussed and should never happen again. This should definitely be caught since we are using the correct warning flags, right?

Comment: I have to agree with @usr here, you can see my live godbolt examples in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31746063/1708801), at least for clang this does not kind'of work.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman UB means it can do anything at all including inserting code. It literally can format your disk. In practice other nasty things happen.

Comment: But in this case just the value is undefinied, isn’t it? I mean, it’s not like the whole behaviour of the program is suddenly undefinied just because you use an unitialized variable somewhere.

Comment: @Michael Actually, it is. If a program has undefined behaviour at any point, the compiler can optimise your program in a way that affects code *preceding* that invoking the undefined behaviour. There are various articles and demonstrations of how mind boggling this can get  Here's quite a good one: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/06/27/10537746.aspx (which includes the bit in the standard that says all bets are off if any path in your program invokes UB)

Comment: @usr: Prior to roughly 2010, the effect of Undefined Behavior could be viewed as equivalent to overwriting all of RAM (including the stack) with arbitrary values and jumping to a random location, but on a Harvard-architecture machine with non-writable code store (common in the embedded-systems world) a program could offer certain guarantees about its behavior even under such circumstances.  Indeed, some systems require that it be impossible for a program to trigger certain hardware actions even if a power glitch causes RAM to get trashed.  Since 2010, however, Undefined Behavior in C...

Comment: ...goes beyond even the "arbitrarily rewrite everything in memory and jump to an arbitrary address" fault model.

Comment: @supercat what happened in 2010? More aggressive compilers?

Comment: @tbleher: When the Standard was written, saying "Reading an uninitialized variable may yield an arbitrary value, or may trap in a fashion which is outside the jurisdiction of this Standard; the documentation for an implementation must specify which" would have been, from a requirements standpoint, equivalent to saying that the standard imposes no requirements, save only for the fact that the lack of anything in a compiler's documentation regarding its behavior would be equivalent to specifying that it the compiler may interpret the action as triggering a trap which frees the system from...

Comment: ...the jurisdiction of the Standard.  I really doubt that the original authors of the Standard envisioned the idea, which seems to have emerged around 2010, that a compiler should try to identify inputs which would result in a program to invoke Undefined Behavior, and then eliminate any code which would be irrelevant unless such inputs were received.  I'm not quite clear that anyone actually benefits from granting compilers such freedom, since imposing somewhat tighter rules on how compilers must interpret most forms of UB would make it possible for many programs to meet requirements...

Comment: ...more efficiently than is possible using only actions defined by the current Standard.  Many programs have two requirements: (1) When given valid input, produce strictly-defined output; (2) Don't launch nuclear missiles when given invalid input. If (with `int` being 32 bits) `x<<y` were defined as arbitrarily yielding `x<<(y & 31)` or `y & ~31 ? 0 : x<<y`, code which would be happy with either value when fed inputs that caused `y` to exceed 31 could let machines where one operation would be cheaper than the other use the cheaper operation. Making it UB means compilers can't get that freedom.

Comment: @supercat: Your claim that something changed in or around 2010 is unsupported and wrong. There have always been lots of bad things possible from UB, and many/most of the bad things that can happen from UB due to optimizing compiles *happen even if the compiler does not go out of its way to break code with UB*. There are a very small limited class of UB cases the compiler can detect at compile-time, and therefore would have the freedom to "avoid breaking" (i.e. "do what the programmer expected"), but this blows up and requires very expensive runtime checks in the general case.

Comment: This answer makes it sound as if *"invoking undefined behavior is bad in theory, but it won't really hurt you much in practice"*. That's wrong. Collecting entropy from an expression that would cause UB *can* (and probably *will*) cause [all the previously collected entropy to be lost](http://kqueue.org/blog/2012/06/25/more-randomness-or-less/). This is a serious hazard.

Comment: @R..: What is the earliest you know of that anyone has advocated the idea that compilers should endeavor to use UB to make inferences about what inputs a piece of code could receive, and eliminate dead paths based upon such inferences?  I'm well aware that compilers have made certain inferences about integer arithmetic going back even before 2000, but all such inferences I know of could be characterized under a computation model I refer to as "Partially-Indeterminate Value".  If `int` is 16 bits, then after `unsigned char b=200; int i=b*b;`, each use of `i` as an rvalue could...

Comment: ...independently behave as any number (representable or not) which was congruent to 40000 mod 65536.  Such behavior could cause confusion for code that expected two's-complement wrapping the Standard generally would generally require when casting a 32-bit `int` to an `int16_t`, but if `i` was used in a fashion such that any number congruent to 40000 mod 65536 would allow the program to meet its requirements, there would be no reason for the programmer to constrain the compiler by e.g. using `unsigned` rather than `int`.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis: Even in cases where it is possible to read uninitialized memory without causing Undefined Behavior (and there are some), and even in cases where a compiler wouldn't be able to tell that code was reading uninitialized memory, there could be a correlation between the values that were read and the existing "entropy collection".  If one has a `uint64_t seed;` and `uint8_t arbitrary[1];`, coded such that reads of the latter yield an Unspecified value that a compiler can't optimize away, the code `seed += arbitrary[0];` could lose a bit of entropy if `arbitrary[0]` is...

Comment: ...always even when `seed` is even and odd when it is odd [e.g. because its value was copied from storage that had been used in the last computation of `seed`].  There are times when reading unintialized data might provide a very feeble source of entity to a program at a time when it would otherwise have *none* available (e.g. if many identical embedded processors in a network being powered on simultaneously and need to establish arbitrary unique ids, timing divergence may eventually work, but any entropy that can be used to start the process may help greatly) but such cases are rare.

Comment: @R..: I would be genuinely interested in seeing evidence that the use of UB to make inferences about program *inputs* was advocated prior to 2009-2010. My claim that something changed around then is predicated upon my having read articles from around that time period advocating that compilers make use of such inferences, but not having seen evidence of such things having been advocated previously.  Also, I'd say that the fact that neither the C89 nor C99 standard makes any mention that the effects of Undefined Behavior can be retroactive, but the C11 standard does, is indicative of a change.

Comment: "I'd fire you?"  What an arrogant thing to say.  He was trying to come up with a creative way of solving a problem.  Hopefully nobody works for you.

Comment: @FrostRocket: People who insist on doing things that are documented as wrong and unsafe for the sake of being "creative" are a liability to a project, whether it's commercial or FOSS. The remark you're replying to may have been unnecessarily inflammatory, but the sentiment that people need to stop doing this or get out is quite valid.

Comment: @supercat: What you wrote before ("Prior to roughly 2010, the effect of Undefined Behavior could be viewed as equivalent to overwriting all of RAM ...but...a program could offer certain guarantees about its behavior even under such circumstances") has nothing to do with what you're claiming now, that DCE based on UB was introduced around 2010. Even without UB-based DCE, UB is much more dangerous than you're giving it credit for.

Comment: @R..: There are many circumstances where programs which receive invalid input is allowed to produce arbitrary output, subject to relatively few constraints. The way many platforms have historically treated things like integer overflow (e.g. `x-y>z` might arbitrarily yield 0 or 1 if `x-y` overflows, but wouldn't launch nukes in any case) made it possible to meet that requirement cheaply, while allowing optimizations on some platforms that would not be possible if the code were rewritten as `(int)((unsigned)x-y)>z`.

Comment: @R..: Do you suppose the pattern `(x << y) | (x >> (32-y))` appeared because the authors were fools, or because until recently every compiler for a machine with 32-bit integers would evaluate it correctly?  If all instances of that code which are required to work when y==0 were replaced with `(x << y) | (x >> (31-y) >> 1)` would any *useful* optimizations be possible that would not have been possible if the standard had been changed to require that `x>>32` had to yield either `x` or 0 at the compiler's option?

Comment: @supercat: I'm not trying to have an argument over the merits declaring certain particular things undefined. That is a huge discussion and it's off-topic here. What I am saying is that you claim that UB was relatively safe before 2010, and that aggressive compiler optimizations using UB for DCE made it unsafe, is unsupported, and in my view, false. Non-obvious (to the compiler) cases of invalid aliasing, sequence point violations, access to uninitialized objects, etc. can all lead to things like inconsistent evaluation of expressions at different points, which is very unsafe.

Comment: This answer, even though thoroughly upvoted, is unfortunately factually incorrect. I would advise you to read Shafik's answer, as well as the [What every C programmer should know about undefined behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html) to get a better grasp on the subtleties of undefined behavior (the short of it: the compiler expects that undefined behavior never happens, and is allowed to delete any branch of code that would trigger it).

Comment: #### I have edited this answer to make it (more) clear that UB is not something anyone except compiler writers are equipped to deal with. ####

Comment: @R.. They *can*. Could they before approximately 2010?

Comment: _"Also, I'd fire you."_  Perhaps.  But we're in Undefined Behaviour land here.  You might end up giving him a raise :)

Comment: @immibis: I don't have a test case in front of me right now, but conceptually there's no reason they shouldn't be able to happen. All that should be needed to trigger inconsistent evaluations related to illegal aliasing is perturbing things enough to affect register spills, and this kind of issue is going to happen on any compiler that's not so idiotic as to load/store on *every single access* in the abstract machine (i.e. treat all objects as `volatile`).

Comment: @R..: If an variable is written one way and read another, in violation of the Strict Aliasing Rule (or any of the aliasing rules which some compilers could optionally enable prior to C99) a traditional behavioral model would imply that a compiler could create a separate object for each mode of accessing that variable, and arbitrarily copy the value of any such object at any time to any of the other objects associated with the same variable (in addition to copying the values at certain well-defined times).  In many cases, this could be disastrous, but if an algorithm would work correctly...

Comment: ...for any combination of read/write visibility consistent with the model [perhaps better for some such combinations than others], coding the algorithm in a fashion that gives a compiler flexibility would (on a compiler which promised not to do anything beyond what such a model would allow) enable optimizations that would not be possible if code couldn't request any actions beyond those permitted by the Standard.

Comment: @immibis: Compilers have for a long time made certain inferences about the behavior of integer arithmetic in loops which might at first glance appear to violate causality, but could instead be described in terms of linear transformations. A 16-bit compiler might rewrite `int i,n; long total; ... for (i=n; i>=0; i--) total+=i*3000;` a 16-bit compiler might assume an execution model where integers have enough extra bits to avoid overflow and transform the code to `for (i=n*3000; i>=0; i-=3000) total+=i;`, which might end up executing the loop 0 times when e.g. n is 11.  On the other hand,...

Comment: ...there's a difference between saying that certain kinds of transforms which would preserve semantics under such an execution model may be performed even if the platform uses a different execution model, and saying that any form of UB throws all behavioral requirements out the window.

Comment: @supercat: My argument is not that there don't exist specific invalid programs for which you can nonetheless prove theorems about their behavior given knowledge of a specific compiler's transformations, but rather that, **in general**, programs with undefined behavior were unsafe even prior to 2010. In particular, whenever the same expression can evaluate differently at different points due to UB, you can end up with bypassed bounds checks, etc.

Comment: @R..: On 16-bit machines, under a long-standing common behavioral model, given `int x=32767; int y=x+1;` the value of `y` might sometimes behave as +32768 and sometimes as -32768; it might also sometimes behave as any other numbers congruent to 32768 mod 65536.  Because bounds-checks like `if (y >= 0 && y <  50) foo(y);` could very well get bypassed, code needed to ensure that any values which might have overflowed were only used in situations where such inconsistent behavior couldn't pose a danger.  In cases where any value that was congruent to the arithmetically-correct one mod 65536...

Comment: ...would suffice to meet program requirements, however, code which only needed to run on platforms which fit that behavioral model could offer more optimization opportunities to compilers which would abide by that model, than would code which was used only Standard-defined behaviors.

Comment: I believe the "go back in time" argument is subtly wrong -- the compiler can only "go back" in time if the code path leading to UB has no observable side effects, but in that case, you wouldn't be able to tell if it "went back" or not. If you do anything observable inside `ring_bell()` (e.g. writing to a file), that action *must* actually happen before UB is invoked. The compiler cannot assume at *compile-time* that it would be able to "undo" this action at run-time, because there is no guarantee it will be able to -- the call is external and, for example, may never even return.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question which is 'Is uninitialized local variable the fastest random number generator?'

Comment: @Mehrdad: A compiler may reorder UB across side-effects if is allowed to assume that the code performing the side-effects will neither block perpetually nor cause an abnormal program termination in implementation-defined manner (such as attempting to send data to a broken pipe).  Unfortunately, few implementations bother to document which operations they do or do not recognize as possibly disrupting program execution, because it so seldom matters.

Comment: @supercat: I was saying the problem is that "if" cannot be satisfied in reality, because the *compiler* has no idea what the system that actually ends up *running* the program will do as a result of that side effect (the program does not contain enough information about this! it's the outside world and unobservable by definition!) and hence no idea of how long that action will take (if finite) or whether it is even possible to undo the result (if any). So it's forced to make the side effect occur and cannot optimize UB across it.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Implementations are not required to specify any particular relation between anything that happens in the abstract machine and anything that happens in the real world.  An implementation couldn't be useful for much of anything if it couldn't guarantee some kind of meaningful relationship, but the authors of the Standard state in the rationale that they don't think it's necessary to avoid the possibility of conforming-but-useless implementations.

Comment: @supercat: We were talking about a *compiler* (takes in source code, spits out some translation to be run later on some implementation), not the actual abstract "implementation" itself (takes in source code, executes it in some abstract fashion). You can't call it a compiler if it's the final entity executing the code; you'd call it an "interpreter" or something else.

Comment: @Mehrdad: The Standard can't say anything meaningful about what happens if a compiler's output is run in an environment that doesn't meet requirements.  A conforming compiler could specify that it is only suitable for use in environments that promise that every facially-valid call to `fwrite` will return, and that it makes no promises about what will happen if a call to `fwrite` fails to do so.  A compiler that specifies things in such fashion would be free to reorder operations that may invoke UB across calls to fwrite(), even though fwrite() has observable side-effects.

Comment: @supercat: Yes, and I don't think that contradicts anything I said. I only ever talked about program a *compiler* can produce; it doesn't even make *sense* to talk about "optimizing out" code when talking about purely the abstract machine. You *need* intermediate introspection. Indeed a compiler can produce output that tells the run-time system "here's what you do if you know a priori what `fwrite` can do, and here's what you do if not", and the implementation can use that *if that's the case*. But we *know* that's vacuous for *our* implementations, so we only care about the "if not" case.

Comment: @supercat: As a side note, the standard doesn't have to say anything about compiler output explicitly. Whatever the compiler produces must be logically implied by the original program if executed with valid inputs, and the standard does have something to say about *that*, and that is very much a nontrivial constraint. (But again, note that I was talking about the compiler the whole time, not the final abstract machine: "optimizing out" has no meaning unless you can assume *something* concrete that you can introspect.)

Comment: @Mehrdad: Consider the function `void test(FILE *f, unsigned x) { for (int i=0; i<10; i++) { char temp= !x; fwrite(&temp, 1, 1, f); temp = 1/x; fwrite(&temp, 1, 1, f);  } }`.  If a compiler specifies that it is only suitable for environments where a facially-valid `fwrite` will always return, it could hoist the computation of `1/x` outside the loop.  Such an optimization would often be useful, but could cause UB to time-travel across the first fwrite call.  Even if the generated code for `1/x` doesn't actually trap when x==0 (e.g. a compiler could replace `1/x` with `x==1`)...

Comment: ...a compiler could assume that the expression `!x` won't be reachable with `x==0`.

Comment: @supercat: Yes,  I believe that statement is consistent with what I just said, and that a compiler would not be able to actually make this optimization because of what I also just explained.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I'm not clear why you think a compiler would be unable to make such an optimization.  I'm not sure any make it with `fwrite`, but if one replaced the fwrite with a store to a volatile object, gcc would make that optimization even though on many platforms a volatile store may have externally-observable effects.

Comment: @supercat: Is GCC legally allowed to assume that a write to a volatile guaranteed to complete in finite time in whatever implementation GCC is targeting? If it is, then that may be where I'm mistaken (I've never read anything claiming this). If not, and if GCC actually does this, I would say it is non-conforming in doing so, with the reasons being everything I've stated. Could you link me to an example supporting your claim that GCC will do this? I'm having trouble reproducing it.

Comment: See https://godbolt.org/g/4EEJ57 for a simple example.  The code performs the division before the loop.  As to whether such behavior is "allowed", I think the Standard would view the sequencing relationships between volatile accesses and things that aren't volatile accesses as a Quality of Implementation issue, and makes no attempt to require that implementations be of sufficient quality to be usable for any particular purpose.

Comment: @supercat: Interesting, thanks. Yes, I see that as an illegal optimization. I don't see how the write to the volatile `zzq` can be inhibited just because a user specified `x = 0`. What if a write to `zzq` were supposed to result in a CPU reboot before the instruction completed? You could probably make actual hardware (or if not, an emulator...) that did this with an x86 ISA. The only justification I see here is if x86 prohibits such a thing, which, if it does, I'm not aware of it.

Comment: @Mehrdad: The Standard gives implementations extremely broad latitude with regard to how they handle `volatile`.  I think the intention is that if there would be any imaginable circumstance where it would be useful for an implementation targeted toward a particular purpose to behave in some particular fashion, an implementation targeted toward that purpose should be allowed to do so if it documents the behavior.  Not unreasonable, if compiler writers recognize that the Standards' allowances for unusual behaviors in no way imply an endorsement of them.

Answer (score 216):

Let me say this clearly: **we do not invoke undefined behavior in our programs**. It is never ever a good idea, period. There are rare exceptions to this rule; for example, if you are a [library implementer implementing offsetof](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6433339/1708801). If your case falls under such an exception you likely know this already. In this case we [know using uninitialized automatic variables is undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23415661/1708801).

Compilers have become very aggressive with optimizations around undefined behavior and we can find many cases where undefined behavior has lead to security flaws. The most infamous case is probably the [Linux kernel null pointer check removal](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/970) which I mention in [my answer to C++ compilation bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32507135/1708801) where a compiler optimization around undefined behavior turned a finite loop into an infinite one.

We can read CERT's [Dangerous Optimizations and the Loss of Causality](https://pubweb.eng.utah.edu/~cs5785/slides-f10/Dangerous+Optimizations.pdf) ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cjQQCrQ_wvs)) which says, amongst other things:

> Increasingly, compiler writers are taking advantage of undefined
>   behaviors in the C and C++ programming languages to improve
>   optimizations.
>
> Frequently, these optimizations are interfering with
>   the ability of developers to perform cause-effect analysis on their
>   source code, that is, analyzing the dependence of downstream results
>   on prior results.
>
> Consequently, these optimizations are eliminating
>   causality in software and are increasing the probability of software
>   faults, defects, and vulnerabilities.

Specifically with respect to indeterminate values, the C standard [defect report 451: Instability of uninitialized automatic variables](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/dr_451.htm) makes for some interesting reading. It has not been resolved yet but introduces the concept of *wobbly values* which means the indeterminatness of a value may propagate through the program and can have different indeterminate values at different points in the program.

I don't know of any examples where this happens but at this point we can't rule it out.

**Real examples, not the result you expect**

You are unlikely to get random values. A compiler could optimize the away the loop altogether. For example, with this simplified case:

```
void updateEffect(int  arr[20]){
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
        int r ;    
        arr[i] = r ;
    }
}
```

clang optimizes it away (*[see it live](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%2C%22colouriseAsm%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22FANw9glgJgBArgBygQwC4FMCiAzb6DGqAFBAHaowzIBO1A2gEwAMAugJQDewll2Y1JcjAgBeJgG4IAHmaSA1HM7ceKshWoxxK5Sso16EFjBEwN4nTAC%2Bwa0A%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22clang37x%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-std%3Dc%2B%2B14%20-O3%20-Wall%20-Wextra%20-fverbose-asm%20-fno-inline%22%7D%5D%7D)*):

```
updateEffect(int*):                     # @updateEffect(int*)
    retq
```

or perhaps get all zeros, as with this modified case:

```
void updateEffect(int  arr[20]){
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
        int r ;    
        arr[i] = r%255 ;
    }
}
```

[see it live](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%2C%22colouriseAsm%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22FANw9glgJgBArgBygQwC4FMCiAzb6DGqAFBAHaowzIBO1A2gEwAMAugJQDewll2Y1JcjAgBeJgG4IAHmaSA1HM7ceKshWoxxK5Sso16EFjBExqAUgYBWS5p0wAvsEdAA%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22clang37x%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-std%3Dc%2B%2B14%20-O3%20-Wall%20-Wextra%20-fverbose-asm%20-fno-inline%22%7D%5D%7D):

```
updateEffect(int*):                     # @updateEffect(int*)
    xorps   %xmm0, %xmm0
    movups  %xmm0, 64(%rdi)
    movups  %xmm0, 48(%rdi)
    movups  %xmm0, 32(%rdi)
    movups  %xmm0, 16(%rdi)
    movups  %xmm0, (%rdi)
    retq
```

Both of these cases are perfectly acceptable forms of undefined behavior.

Note, if we are on an Itanium we could [end up with a trap value](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/papers/ub:apsys12.pdf):

> [...]if the register happens to hold a special not-a-thing value,
>   reading the register traps except for a few instructions[...]

**Other important notes**

It is interesting to note the [variance between gcc and clang noted in the UB Canaries project](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/1234) over how willing they are to take advantage of undefined behavior with respect to uninitialized memory. The article notes (*emphasis mine*):

> Of course we need to be completely clear with ourselves that any such expectation has nothing to do with the language standard and everything to do with what a particular compiler happens to do, either because the providers of that compiler are unwilling to exploit that UB **or just because they have not gotten around to exploiting it yet**. When no real guarantee from the compiler provider exists, **we like to say that as-yet unexploited UBs are time bombs**: they’re waiting to go off next month or next year when the compiler gets a bit more aggressive.

As Matthieu M. points out [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior #2/3](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html) is also relevant to this question. It says amongst other things (*emphasis mine*):

> The important and scary thing to realize is that **just about *any*
>   optimization based on undefined behavior can start being triggered on
>   buggy code at any time in the future**. Inlining, loop unrolling, memory
>   promotion and other optimizations will keep getting better, and a
>   significant part of their reason for existing is to expose secondary
>   optimizations like the ones above.
>
> To me, this is deeply dissatisfying, partially because the compiler
>   inevitably ends up getting blamed, but also because it means that huge
>   bodies of C code are **land mines just waiting to explode.**

For completeness sake I should probably mention that implementations can choose to make undefined behavior well defined, for example [gcc allows type punning through unions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Type-punning) while [in C++ this seems like undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-undefined). If this is the case the implementation should document it and this will usually not be portable.

Comment: +(int)(PI/3) for the compiler output examples; a real-life example that UB is, well, *UB*.

Comment: Utilizing UB effectively used to be the trademark of an excellent hacker. This tradition has gone on for probably 50 years or more now. Unfortunately, computers are now required to minimize the effects of UB because of Bad People. I really enjoyed figuring out how to do cool things with UB machine code or port read/writes, etc I  the 90s, when the OS wasn't as capable of protecting the user from themselves.

Comment: @sfdcfox there is little out there that documents this transition, at least I have not found it and I have read a lot on this topic. It seems unlikely this genie will be put back into the bottle.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis considering my answer came almost six hours after the question was asked I am doing pretty well. With these hot network question it is very hard to overcome first mover advantage. I only added my answer because the existing answers really left out a lot of important points. Most likely the only way I will end up on top is if the OP accepts my answer.

Comment: @sfdcfox if you were doing it in machine code / assembler, it wasn't undefined behavior (it may have been unconventional behavior).

Comment: @Caleth: There are many platforms where certain kinds of pointer operations will have useful behaviors even though the Standard imposes no requirements on them.  For example, `void copy(char *dest, char *src { char ch; int diff = dest-src-1; while((ch = *src++) != 0); src[diff] = ch; }`  Horrible Undefined Behavior, but if `src` and `dest` are known to be close enough, it can yield better code than any defined alternative.

Comment: If you have a specific assembly in mind, then use that and don't write uncompliant C. Then everyone will know you are using a specific non-portable trick. And it's not Bad People who mean you can't use UB, it's Intel etc doing their tricks on chip.

Comment: You might also want to link to [What every C programmer should know about Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html). Now, let's wish this answer takes the top...

Comment: Aside, and probably a stupid question with a simple answer: Why are operations that are explicitly Undefined Behavior according to the standard not simply disallowed completely?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError because they may not be easily detectable or may not be detectable at all in the general case and therefore there would be no way to disallow them. Which is different then violations of the grammar which can be detected. We also have ill-formed and ill-formed no diagnostic required which in general separates poorly formed programs that could be detected in theory from those that in theory could not be reliably detected.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError the second reason is that it allows compilers to support extensions ... or support the behavior on platforms that are not problematic.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: Consider effect of `unsigned int x,y; x=getch(); y=getch(); printf("%u",x<<y);` on a 32-bit machine.  Some machines would generate code that would shift `x` left by `y` times.  Others would use a shift-left instruction that would compute `x<<(y & 31)`.  Some might trigger a hardware trap if `y` exceeds 32.  If the Standard had mandate one or the other of the first two behaviors, that would require many compilers to generate extra code to handle the `y>=32` case which would slow down performance even when `y` was in the 0 to 31 range.  Even worse, if...

Comment: ...e.g. the hardware could perform the "shift left N times" behavior in a single cycle, and a program needed the "shift left N times" behavior but the Standard had mandated the "shift left (N & 31)" times, a programmer would have to write `y >= 32 ? 0 : x << y` which a typical compiler would then most likely render as a a comparison, conditional jump, bit-mask, and shift--quite possibly taking four times as long as a "shift x left by y" instruction.  The effect was that programmers who knew that their code would only have to run on a platform whose behavior matched their needs could...

Comment: ...take advantage of that.  Someone writing code for a platform which didn't match their needs would have to write code to deal with that, but requiring that the user write code to handle the y>=32 case *in situations where the platform behavior wasn't acceptable* was better than requiring compilers for about half the platforms in existence to generate such code even when it would often be useless and sometimes downright counterproductive.

Comment: I find the linked Defect Report 451 and the committee's response interesting. Semantics where the first read of uninitialized data may read any value, but all subsequent reads must yield the same value (absent intervening writes) make it possible for programmers who know that an algorithm will work with an array holding any combination of contents to refrain from needless initialization.  I'm hard-pressed to imagine any cases where weakening the semantics to the extent described would allow any optimizations in any programs *written to behave meaningfully under those semantics*.

Comment: There are many situations where code receives a number which is small enough to use as an array index, and needs to compute from that a value which can be readily verified as correct.  Fetching a value from an uninitialized array, determining whether it's correct, and--if not--computing the value and storing the computed value in the array, may sometimes be more efficient than initializing the array, especially in situations where only a tiny fraction of array elements are ever used.  Having the elements read indeterminate rather than unspecified, however...

Comment: ...would totally break such an algorithm.  BTW, I'm also curious why the authors of the response think a description of padding bits as "unspecified" implies that "unspecified" and "indeterminate" are the same thing?  If `long` is 40 bits plus 24 bits of padding at the end, given `union { long l; unsigned char b[8];} u`, making them unspecified would say that each run of `u.l=123; printf("(%d %d)", u.b[7], u.b[7]);` must output some number 0-255 twice, but each run could output a different number.  Making it indeterminate would make that code UB.  Is the latter even remotely reasonable?

Comment: `Dangerous Optimizations and the Loss of Causality` now [found here](http://www.eng.utah.edu/~cs5785/slides-f10/Dangerous+Optimizations.pdf) also [see the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cjQQCrQ_wvs)

Comment: Almost any code that uses aggregates violates 6.5p7 and consequently invokes UB.  The authors of the Standard presumably expected that any quality implementation should recognize at least some situations where an lvalue of one type is used to derive one of another, and thought it so obvious that the constructs "aggregate.member" and "aggregatePtr->member" should be supported by all usable-quality implementations that they shouldn't need explicit mention.

Answer (score 166):

No, it's terrible.

The behaviour of using an uninitialised variable is undefined in both C and C++, and it's very unlikely that such a scheme would have desirable statistical properties.

If you want a "quick and dirty" random number generator, then `rand()` is your best bet. In its implementation, all it does is a multiplication, an addition, and a modulus.

The fastest generator I know of requires you to use a `uint32_t` as the type of the pseudo-random variable `I`, and use

`I = 1664525 * I + 1013904223`

to generate successive values. You can choose any initial value of `I` (called the *seed*) that takes your fancy. Obviously you can code that inline. The standard-guaranteed wraparound of an unsigned type acts as the modulus. (The numeric constants are hand-picked by that remarkable scientific programmer Donald Knuth.)

Comment: The "linear congruential" generator that you present is good for simple applications, but only for non-cryptographic applications. It is possible to predict its behavior. See for example "[Deciphering a linear congruential encryption](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=1056997)" by Don Knuth himself (IEEE Transactions on Information Theory, Volume 31)

Comment: @Jay compared to an unitialized variable for quick and dirty? This is a much better solution.

Comment: `rand()` is not fit for purpose and should be entirely deprecated, in my opinion. These days you can download freely licensed and vastly superior random number generators (e.g Mersenne Twister) which are very nearly as fast with the greatest of ease so there's really no need to continue using the highly defective `rand()`

Comment: rand() has another terrible issue: it uses a kind of lock, called inside threads it slows down your code dramatically. At least, there's a reentrant version. And if you use C++11, the random API provides everything you need.

Comment: Although `rand()` must be seeded (otherwise it won't look remotely random). Since that typically uses the time, you'd have a sys call in there as well. Still extremely acceptable performance in virtually any case, though (and seeding is a one time thing).

Comment: To be fair he didn't ask if it was a good random number generator. He asked if it was fast. Well, yes, it's probably the fasted., But the results will not be very random at all.

Answer (score 42):

Good question!

Undefined does not mean it's random.  Think about it, the values you'd get in global uninitialized variables were left there by the system or your/other applications running. Depending what your system does with no longer used memory and/or what kind of values the system and applications generate, you may get:

1. Always the same.
2. Be one of a small set of values.
3. Get values in one or more small ranges.
4. See many values dividable by 2/4/8 from pointers on 16/32/64-bit system
5. ...

The values you'll get completely depend on which non-random values are left by the system and/or applications.  So, indeed there will be some noise (unless your system wipes no longer used memory), but the value pool from which you'll draw will by no means be random.

Things get much worse for local variables because these come directly from the stack of your own program.  There is a very good chance that your program will actually write these stack locations during the execution of other code.  I estimate the chances for luck in this situation very low, and a 'random' code change you make tries this luck.

Read about [randomness](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness). As you'll see randomness is a very specific and hard to obtain property. It's a common mistake to think that if you just take something that's hard to track (like your suggestion) you'll get a random value.

Comment: ... and that's leaving out all the compiler-optimizations which would completely gut that code.

Comment: 6 ...  You will get different "randomness" in Debug and Release.  Undefined means you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Right.  I'd abbreviate or summarize with "undefined" != "arbitrary" != "random".  All these kinds of "unknownness" have different properties.

Comment: Global variables are guaranteed to have a defined value, whether explicitly initialized or not.  [This is definitely true in C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) and [in C as well](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/initialization).

Answer (score 33):

Many good answers, but allow me to add another and stress the point that in a deterministic computer, nothing is random. This is true for both the numbers produced by an pseudo-RNG and the seemingly "random" numbers found in areas of memory reserved for C/C++ local variables on the stack.

BUT... there is a crucial difference.

The numbers generated by a good pseudorandom generator have the properties that make them statistically similar to truly random draws. For instance, the distribution is uniform. The cycle length is long: you can get millions of random numbers before the cycle repeats itself. The sequence is not autocorrelated: for instance, you will not begin to see strange patterns emerge if you take every 2nd, 3rd, or 27th number, or if you look at specific digits in the generated numbers.

In contrast, the "random" numbers left behind on the stack have none of these properties. Their values and their apparent randomness depend entirely on how the program is constructed, how it is compiled, and how it is optimized by the compiler. By way of example, here is a variation of your idea as a self-contained program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

notrandom()
{
        int r, g, b;

        printf("R=%d, G=%d, B=%d", r&255, g&255, b&255);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
                notrandom();
                printf("\n");
        }

        return 0;
}
```

When I compile this code with GCC on a Linux machine and run it, it turns out to be rather unpleasantly deterministic:

```
R=0, G=19, B=0
R=130, G=16, B=255
R=130, G=16, B=255
R=130, G=16, B=255
R=130, G=16, B=255
R=130, G=16, B=255
R=130, G=16, B=255
R=130, G=16, B=255
R=130, G=16, B=255
R=130, G=16, B=255
```

If you looked at the compiled code with a disassembler, you could reconstruct what was going on, in detail. The first call to notrandom() used an area of the stack that was not used by this program previously; who knows what was in there. But after that call to notrandom(), there is a call to printf() (which the GCC compiler actually optimizes to a call to putchar(), but never mind) and that overwrites the stack. So the next and subsequent times, when notrandom() is called, the stack will contain stale data from the execution of putchar(), and since putchar() is always called with the same arguments, this stale data will always be the same, too.

So there is absolutely *nothing* random about this behavior, nor do the numbers obtained this way have any of the desirable properties of a well-written pseudorandom number generator. In fact, in most real-life scenarios, their values will be repetitive and highly correlated.

Indeed, as others, I would also seriously consider firing someone who tried to pass off this idea as a "high performance RNG".

Comment: “in a deterministic computer, nothing is random” — This isn’t actually true. Modern computers contain all kinds of sensors that allow you to produce *true*, unpredictable randomness without separate hardware generators. On a modern architecture, the values of `/dev/random` are often seeded from such hardware sources, and are in fact “quantum noise”, i.e. truly unpredictable in the best physical sense of the word.

Comment: But then, that's not a deterministic computer, is it? You are now relying on environmental input. In any case, this takes us well beyond the discussion of a conventional pseudo-RNG vs. "random" bits in uninitialized memory. Also... look at the description of /dev/random to appreciate just how far out of their way the implementers went to ensure that the random numbers are cryptographically secure... precisely because the input sources are not pure, uncorrelated quantum noise but rather, potentially highly correlated sensor readings with only a small degree of randomness. It's pretty slow, too.

Answer (score 29):

Undefined behavior means that the authors of compilers are free to ignore the problem because programmers will never have a right to complain whatever happens.

While in theory when entering UB land **anything can happen** (including a [daemon flying off your nose](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nasal+demons)) what normally means is that compiler authors just won't care and, for local variables, the value will be whatever is in the stack memory at that point.

This also means that often the content will be "strange" but fixed or slightly random or variable but with a clear evident pattern (e.g. increasing values at each iteration).

For sure you **cannot** expect it being a decent random generator.

Answer (score 28):

Undefined behaviour is undefined. It doesn't mean that you get an undefined value, it means that the the program can do *anything* and still meet the language specification.

A good optimizing compiler should take

```
void updateEffect(){
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
        int r;
        int g;
        int b;
        star[i].setColor(r%255,g%255,b%255);
        bool isVisible;
        star[i].setVisible(isVisible);
    }
}
```

and compile it to a noop. This is certainly faster than any alternative. It has the downside that it will not do anything, but such is the downside of undefined behaviour.

Comment: A lot depends on whether the purpose of a compiler is help programmers produce executable files that meet domain requirements, or whether the purpose is to produce the most "efficient" executable whose behavior will be consistent with the minimal requirements of the the C Standard, without regard for whether such behavior will serve any useful purpose.  With regard to the former objective, having code use some arbitrary initial values for r,g,b, or triggering a debugger trap if practical, would be more useful than turning the code into a nop.  With regard to the latter objective...

Comment: ...an optimal compiler should determine what inputs would cause the above method to execute, and eliminate any code which would only be relevant when such inputs are received.

Comment: @supercat Or its purpose could be C. to produce efficient executables in compliance with the Standard while helping the programmer find places where compliance may not be useful. Compilers can meet this compromise purpose by emitting more diagnostics than the Standard requires, such as GCC's `-Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: That the values are undefined does not mean that the behavior of surrounding code is undefined. No compiler should noop that function. The two function calls, whatever inputs they're given, absolutely MUST be called; the first MUST be called with three numbers between 0 and 255, and the second MUST be called with either a true or false value.

A "good optimizing compiler" could optimize the function params to arbitrary static values, getting rid of the variables completely, but that's as far as it could go (well, unless the functions themselves could be reduced to noops on certain inputs).

Comment: @DewiMorgan - as the functions called are of the "set this parameter" type, they almost certainly do reduce to noops when the input is the same as the current value of the parameter, which the compiler is free to assume is the case.

Comment: "That the values are undefined does not mean that the behavior of surrounding code is undefined"  It absolutely does mean that in both C and C++.  If you don't like that, using a different language.

Answer (score 18):

Because of security reasons, new memory assigned to a program has to be cleaned, otherwise the information could be used, and passwords could leak from one application into another. Only when you reuse memory, you get different values than 0. And it is very likely, that on a stack the previous value is just fixed, because the previous use of that memory is fixed.

Answer (score 18):

Not mentioned yet, but code paths that invoke undefined behavior are allowed to do whatever the compiler wants, e.g.

```
void updateEffect(){}
```

Which is certainly faster than your correct loop, and because of UB, is perfectly conformant.

Answer (score 13):

Your particular code example would probably not do what you are expecting.  While technically each iteration of the loop re-creates the local variables for the r, g, and b values, in practice it's the exact same memory space on the stack.  Hence it won't get re-randomized with each iteration, and you will end up assigning the same 3 values for each of the 1000 colors, regardless of how random the r, g, and b are individually and initially.

Indeed, if it did work, I would be very curious as to what's re-randomizing it.  The only thing I can think of would be an interleaved interrupt that piggypacked atop that stack, highly unlikely.  Perhaps internal optimization that kept those as register variables rather than as true memory locations, where the registers get re-used further down in the loop, would do the trick, too, especially if the set visibility function is particularly register-hungry.  Still, far from random.

Answer (score 12):

As most of people here mentioned undefined behavior. Undefined also means that you may get some valid integer value (luckily) and in this case this will be faster (as rand function call is not made).
But don't practically use it. I am sure this will terrible results as luck is not with you all the time.

Comment: Very good point!  It may be a pragmatic trick, but indeed one that requires luck.

Comment: There is absolutely no luck involved. If the compiler does not optimize the undefined behavior away, the values that you get will be perfectly deterministic (= depend entirely on your program, its inputs, its compiler, the libraries it uses, the timing of its threads if it has threads). The problem is that you can't *reason* about these values since they depend on implementation details.

Comment: In the absence of an operating system with an interrupt-handling stack separate from the application stack, luck may well be involved, since interrupts will frequently disturb the contents of memory slightly beyond the current stack contents.

Answer (score 12):

Really bad! Bad habit, bad result.
Consider:

```
A_Function_that_use_a_lot_the_Stack();
updateEffect();
```

If the function `A_Function_that_use_a_lot_the_Stack()` make always the same initialization it leaves the stack with the same data on it. That data is what we get calling `updateEffect()`: **always same value!**.

Answer (score 12):

I performed a very simple test, and it wasn't random at all.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int a;
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Every time I ran the program, it printed the same number (`32767` in my case) -- you can't get much less random than that. This is presumably whatever the startup code in the runtime library left on the stack. Since it uses the same startup code every time the program runs, and nothing else varies in the program between runs, the results are perfectly consistent.

Comment: Good point. A result strongly depends on where this "random" number generator is called in the code. It is rather unpredictable than random.

Answer (score 10):

You need to have a definition of what you mean by 'random'.
A sensible definition involves that the values you get should have little correlation. That's something you can measure. It's also not trivial to achieve in a controlled, reproducible manner. So undefined behaviour is certainly not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 7):

There are certain situations in which uninitialized memory may be safely read using type "unsigned char*" [e.g. a buffer returned from `malloc`].  Code may read such memory without having to worry about the compiler throwing causality out the window, and there are times when it may be more efficient to have code be prepared for anything memory might contain than to ensure that uninitialized data won't be read (a commonplace example of this would be using `memcpy` on partially-initialized buffer rather than discretely copying all of the elements that contain meaningful data).

Even in such cases, however, one should always assume that if any combination of bytes will be particularly vexatious, reading it will always yield that pattern of bytes (and if a certain pattern would be vexatious in production, but not in development, such a pattern won't appear until code is in production).

Reading uninitialized memory might be useful as part of a random-generation strategy in an embedded system where one can be sure the memory has never been written with substantially-non-random content since the last time the system was powered on, and if the manufacturing process used for the memory causes its power-on state to vary in semi-random fashion.  Code should work even if all devices always yield the same data, but in cases where e.g. a group of nodes each need to select arbitrary unique IDs as quickly as possible, having a "not very random" generator which gives half the nodes the same initial ID might be better than not having any initial source of randomness at all.

Comment: "if any combination of bytes will be particularly vexatious, reading it will always yield that pattern of bytes" -- until you code to cope with that pattern, at which point it is no longer vexatious and a different pattern will be read in future.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Precisely.  My line about development vs production was intended to convey a similar notion.  Code shouldn't care about what's in uninitialized memory beyond a vague notion of "Some randomness might be nice".  If program behavior is affected by the contents of one piece of uninitialized memory, the contents of pieces that are acquired in future may in turn be affected by that.

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, it will be fast, but not random.

What most compilers will do for local variables is to grab some space for them on the stack, but not bother setting it to anything (the standard says they don't need to, so why slow down the code you're generating?).

In this case, the value you'll get will depend on what was on previously on the stack - if you call a function before this one that has a hundred local char variables all set to 'Q' and then call you're function after that returns, then you'll probably find your "random" values behave as if you've `memset()` them all to 'Q's.

Importantly for your example function trying to use this, these values wont change each time you read them, they'll be the same every time. So you'll get a 100 stars all set to the same colour and visibility.

Also, nothing says that the compiler shouldn't initialize these value - so a future compiler might do so.

In general: bad idea, don't do it.
(like a lot of "clever" code level optimizations really...)

Comment: You're making some strong predictions about what *will* happen although none of that is guaranteed due to UB. It also is not true in practice.

Answer (score 3):

As others have already mentioned, this is undefined behavior (*UB*), but it may "work".

Except from problems already mentioned by others, I see one other problem (disadvantage) - it will not work in any language other than C and C++. I know that this question is about C++, but if you can write code which will be good C++ and Java code and it's not a problem then why not? Maybe some day someone will have to port it to other language and searching for bugs caused by <s>"magic tricks"</s> UB like this definitely will be a nightmare (especially for an inexperienced C/C++ developer).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19559133/conflict-between-a-stanford-tutorial-and-gcc) there is question about another similar UB. Just imagine yourself trying to find bug like this without knowing about this UB. If you want to read more about such strange things in C/C++, read answers for question from link and see [this](http://www.slideshare.net/olvemaudal/deep-c) **GREAT** slideshow. It will help you understand what's under the hood and how it's working; it's not not just another slideshow full of "magic". I'm quite sure that even most of experienced C/c++ programmers can learn a lot from this.

Answer (score 3):

Use `7757` every place you are tempted to use uninitialized variables.  I picked it randomly from a list of prime numbers:

1. it is defined behavior
2. it is guaranteed to not always be 0
3. it is prime
4. it is likely to be as statistically random as uninitualized
   variables
5. it is likely to be faster than uninitialized variables since its
   value is known at compile time

Comment: For comparison, see the results in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31836461/2963099

Answer (score 3):

**Not** a good idea to rely our any logic on language undefined behaviour. In addition to whatever mentioned/discussed in this post, I would like to mention that with modern C++ approach/style such program may not be compile.

This was mentioned in my previous post which contains the advantage of **auto** feature and useful link for the same.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26170069/2724703

So, if we change the above code and replace the actual types with **auto**, the program would not even compile.

```
void updateEffect(){
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
        auto r;
        auto g;
        auto b;
        star[i].setColor(r%255,g%255,b%255);
        auto isVisible;
        star[i].setVisible(isVisible);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I like your way of thinking. Really outside the box. However the tradeoff is really not worth it. *Memory-runtime tradeoff* is a thing, including  undefined behavior for runtime is **not**.

It must give you a very unsettling feeling to know you are using such "random" as your business logic. I woudn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

There is one more possibility to consider.

Modern compilers (ahem g++) are so intelligent that they go through your code to see what instructions affect state, and what don't, and if an instruction is guaranteed to NOT affect the state, g++ will simply remove that instruction.

So here's what will happen. g++ will definitely see that you are reading, performing arithmetic on, saving, what is essentially a garbage value, which produces more garbage. Since there is no guarantee that the new garbage is any more useful than the old one, it will simply do away with your loop. BLOOP!

This method is useful, but here's what I would do. Combine UB (Undefined Behaviour) with rand() speed.

Of course, reduce `rand()`s executed, but mix them in so compiler doesn't do anything you don't want it to.

And I won't fire you.

Comment: I find it very hard to believe a compiler can decide your code is doing something silly and remove it. I'd expect it only to optimise away _unused code_, not _inadvisable_ code. Do you have a reproducible test case? Either way, the recommendation of UB is dangerous. Plus, GCC isn't the only competent compiler around, so it's unfair to single it out as "modern".

Answer (score -1):

Using uninitialized data for randomness is not necessarily a bad thing if done properly.  In fact, OpenSSL does exactly this to seed its PRNG.

Apparently this usage wasn't well documented however, because someone noticed Valgrind complaining about using uninitialized data and "fixed" it, causing a [bug in the PRNG](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2008/05/random_number_b.html).

So you can do it, but you need to know what you're doing and make sure that anyone reading your code understands this.

Comment: This is going to depend in your compiler which is expected with undefined behavior, as we can see [from my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31746063/1708801) clang today will not do what they want.

Comment: That OpenSSL used this method as an entropy input does not say that it was any good. After all, the only other entropy source they used was the *PID*. Not exactly a good random value. From someone who relies on such a bad entropy source, I won't expect good judgement on their other entropy source. I just hope, the people who currently maintain OpenSSL are brighter.