# is a stack pointer a good source of pseudo-random numbers

Tags: c++, c

For example:

```
int main()
{
  int p;

  ::std::cout << ::std::uintptr_t(&p) << ::std::endl;
}
```

This will consistently produce "random" numbers if executed repeatedly. Something similar could be accomplished in C. I don't see anything UB about it.

Comment: it is not UB, but what's the degree of randomness? Who gurantees it?

Comment: The answer for a title: No. Is there UB? Yes, as the value you are getting is undefined. It could be very well always 133.

Comment: I'm not dereferencing the pointer.

Comment: @EugeneSh. From C++ perspective, why's that UB? Sorry, if i'm missing something very silly...

Comment: @EugeneSh. a C equivaluent `int x; printf("%p", (void *)&x);` would be defined, perfectly.

Comment: @RandomDavis and how does that invoke UB?

Comment: As a source of *random numbers* on its own, it's pretty bad because it will be very predictable for a serious adversary. As a source of *entropy* combined with other better sources of entropy, I can't imagine it would hurt. (Again, as long as you use the address and not the value. If you use the value, you'll invoke UB and it can remove your gathered entropy altogether.)

Comment: @ NathanOliver isn't the dupe is about the value?

Comment: Sorry that was the wrong dupe.  You are not actually using the value but the address.

Comment: @RandomDavis, that's not UB. Taking the address of a local variable is very well defined. Casting the pointer value to an int, is very well defined. The standard **names** things as UB. Getting an unknown value does not constitute UB.

Comment: You'll most probably (depending on the CPU) get only even numbers, and even more often numbers divisable by 4 or 8. That is not very random

Comment: @StoryTeller I realized that the second I commented and deleted the comment. Yeah, since the value is not being used, but the address, it's not UB. But definitely not a source of good randomness on its own.

Comment: Also on some systems(like embeded systems) the function may always run in the same memory space so the address will always be the same.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Well.. valid point.. I guess

Comment: @user1095108 That was a mistake.  I opened it already.

Comment: Hi, somebody please clarify what UB stands for. Thanks.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yeah, agreed on it already.

Comment: @SantiagoVillafuerte [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: I believe the unspecified behavior applies. `behavior, for a well-formed program construct and correct data, that depends on the implementation`

Comment: @EugeneSh. next time change your mind more slowy :)

Answer (score 4):

I quite depends on requirements you set on the distribution of the random numbers. Is the sequence 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 random ? Actually hard to tell, but if you make a test for a normal distribution it will certainly fail. Pseudo random number generators are specifically designed to match the properties of the random distribution you want to get from them.

If you do some trickery to get a previously unknown number (on purpose I dont call it random), this number might appear random to you, but it is very likely that there are patterns that you just dont spot.

TL;DR: it is not easy to write a good rng. Use the ones that are available if you need random numbers.

Comment: Mmmm, how about using the stack pointer as a seed to a "proper" pseudo RNG?

Comment: This snippet on some environments will just return the same value *always*. It is a **BAD** entropy source no matter how you put it.

Comment: @user1095108 then you will have a poor quality seed which might defeat the point of using a rng in the first place

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes, but the snippet only. The "RNG" could be used in a function way down or up a call tree.

Comment: @user1095108 It really doesn't matter. Same code on same environment will always produce the same result.

Comment: @user1095108 I'd say that would be acceptable *iff* it was combined with multiple other (higher) quality sources in a `std::seed_seq` which was then ultimately used to seed the generator.

Comment: @user1095108 simply don't. there's no reason to do something stupid like this. Using determinable things is nr1 reasons why weak crypto/auth gets hacked. Simply don't. If you need a seed, use an OS-supplied random number. Most OSes have that, and it's **good**, usually.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Some people appreciate the idea, as you can see. Note, that I asked a question, whether this was OK.

Comment: @user1095108 some people really shouldn't appreciate the idea. Eugene put it perfectly: "*It is a **BAD** entropy source no matter how you put it.*" So simply don't.

Comment: @MarcusMüller They aren't children, if they know C++ well. I think it's a nice addition to C++ lore.

Comment: no, it's not. It's a pattern of bad ideas. Don't do. Don't establish it as practice. I repeat: simply don't. It doesn't do what it's supposed to do, and if it did, that was because it invoces C++ undef behaviour, which you can't rely on, because that might change at any point. So really, it's not a nice addition to anything but a list of things that can be abused.

Answer (score 4):

**No**, *no*, no.

You *cannot* use variable addresses, values of uninitialized variables and the like as sources of random numbers.

Some of those uses will earn you a ticket straight to "undefined behaviour land" where your compiler is allowed to do horrible, *horrible* things to your code.

Some are just *not really* all that random.

If you want random numbers, use what's provided in < [random](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) > and make sure you seed your generator properly if you are not using `random_device` directly (which you probably don't want to for non-crypto-safe numbers).

And don't even consider `rand()` - forget it exists. It is horrible.

You should use a `std::seed_seq` to mix up multiple entropy sources and then use that to seed the generator. Taking the address of a variable as *one of many* inputs for `seed_seq` would be ok, assuming you also include other sources of higher quality (notably `std::random_device`).

Comment: As a comment stressing the point of your answers: **no, it's not a good source**.

Comment: Also, it's **a bad source.** As well as it not being good. Or using it as a source of randomness being a wrong approach. Or actually, the thought of that the address of a variable being random is incorrect. I'm running out of ways to put this.

Comment: You guys are, of course, both right. Which is why I said it is ok only as part of a `seed_seq` where you also add multiple other sources of higher quality. In that case it won't hurt - but won't *help* much either...

Comment: seriously, that's like having the constant `3` as part of your `seed_seq`, just that you hide `3` behind `functon_that_does_something_spectacularly_random()`. It obfuscates the fact that `3` isn't random.

Comment: @Marcus Müller I actually think we agree, so I don't want to start an argument. But let me try to clarify; the whole point of a `seed_seq` is that you can mix up multiple **bad** sources of entropy and get a reasonably good seed out. Now we agree that using the address of a stack variable is horrible as an entropy source, but mixed with other, better sources, it doesn't hurt - and there may actually be a tiny bit of entropy in there when the program is run on different machines (OS'es) and if ASLR is in play, so it's not *quite* as bad as a literal `3` (although close). See what I mean?

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean :) I do think you also see what I mean! So let's shake hands over this.

Comment: @Marcus Müller Done :)

Comment: Reference for uninitialized variables for random number here: [Is uninitialized local variable the fastest random number generator?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31739792/1708801)

Answer (score 4):

If your OS [randomizes the stack address of your program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), you can extract several random bits from the address of your local variable. These will probably be high-quality random bits (if your OS is good), but there will be only a few, because:

- there are strict requirements on alignment (so the low bits will be constant, not random)
- any OS probably constrains the address space of user programs for convenience reasons (so the high bits will be constant)

So this method is not good because its result relies heavily on OS (as an extreme example, a user can disable ASLR, and your random number generator will stop working for that user).

Comment: And also, instead of using the same randomness that the ASLR uses, you use a restricted, partly determinable result of that randomness. Simply use your system's random source; Unixoids usually have /dev/random that works pretty well as source of entropy.

Answer (score 3):

- As a source of *random numbers* on its own, it's pretty bad because it will be very predictable for a serious adversary. As others have said, the address space is limited, the addresses that satisfy the alignment requirements for an `int` are much fewer and, on top of that, the algorithm by which your program gets loaded into memory, if not documented, it at least is not built for much randomness.
- As a source of *entropy*, it depends on the OS. If the OS doesn't randomize, it will hurt readability -- because someone reading your code may mistakenly think that you're adding entropy at that point. If the OS does randomize, it still won't be a great source of entropy, and you'd have to combine it with other better sources to compensate -- and those must be completely independent from the source of entropy of the random address.

In any case, this is all assuming you use the *address* of the variable (perfectly valid) and not its *value* (undefined behavior if uninitialized). If you invoke undefined behavior, the operation could throw away all your entropy.

Comment: well, the source of entropy really only lies in the memory layout, so without address randomization, it's 0 bit of entropy, so yes, by not adding entropy but obfuscating that fact, it *would* hurt, and if there is address radnomization, you should use whatever source of entropy was used to generate that – you'd be wasting bits of entropy, again, otherwise. My guess is that OSes with ASLR will use the same source of entropy at initialization as is available as random device, eg /dev/random, and then will give you a RNG sequence, which doesn't *add* entropy if you can deduct the original seed.

Comment: So, yeah, I think, it should not be done because it's obfuscating the fact that it doesn't help.