# Reference uninitialized variable in C

Tags: c, initialization

What happens, If I reference uninitialized variable? like,

```
void func(int *p)
{
  // My operation
}

int main()
{
  int a;
  func(&a);
}
```

Comment: Taking the address of an uninitialized variable is fine. Trying to read from the address is undefined behavior.

Comment: So it depends on what `func()` does. If it assigns through the pointer it's OK, if it reads it first it's wrong.

Comment: Hopefully you will get a compiler warning that you shouldn't ignore.

Comment: The code as shown is perfectly fine.

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/a/1597426/6764663 for more info

Comment: @Barmar, to satisfy my curiosity, where does the standard say that reading from an uninitialized variable _in itself_ is UB? (Any use of the value can _result_ in UB by the program, but the reading???)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Sorry, I was simplifying. Reading it returns an indeterminate value, which could potentially be a trap representation.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie How do you read a value without using it?

Comment: @Barmar, "use" means to use it further computations. Just reading it is not using it in further computations. Of course that is useless, but we agree that it cannot result in UB.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Does assigning it to another variable count as a use?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: "*where does the standard say that reading from an uninitialized variable in itself is UB*" Please see the C11 Standard's annex  ["*J.2 Undefined Behaviour*"](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2)

Comment: @Barmar, we're getting to the philosophical level :-) Where does UB begin? When indexing an array with it to write, or to read from it and assume you read celcius, or whatever. So what types of UB are there? Compiler UB, program UB, what more?

Comment: The best that can be said was provided by @alk - it's fine as it is.  Like moslty everything, it can be misused:(

Comment: @alk, thanks for pointing me to a 200 bullet point list. Any more detailed pointer?

Comment: @paulogilvie: ... the 11th bullet.

Comment: @alk, thank for the detailed pointer. I appreciate it. It brings us back to "use" and whether accessing the variable is "use" and hence whether that sole access can result in UB. It seems to leave free a compiler inserting a trap that triggers some (software) interrupt upon use, or even upon access. However, I remember a case where the indeterminate value was used as a randomiser.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: The C Standard does not talk about using a "*variable*" but about using its "*value*". Reading a variable in my opinion definitely makes use of its value.

Comment: @alk, found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31739792/is-uninitialized-local-variable-the-fastest-random-number-generator/31746063#31746063, where clang removed a loop that used an unitialized automatic variable. However, there the value was used. Thank you for the discussion.

Answer (score 2):

> What happens, If I reference uninitialized variable

`func()` receives the *address* of the variable `a` as defined in `main()`. Inside `func()` the pointer `pa` defined by `func(int * pa)` points to the memory holding the *indeterminate* value of `a`.

`func()` may assign to `a` by doing

```
*pa = 42;
```

which would set `a` to `42`.

If `func()` did

```
int b  = *pa;
```

it reads *uninitialised* memory, namely the *indeterminate* value of `a`, and this would invoke [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

From the C11 Standard (draft):

> **J.2 Undefined behavior**
>
> 1 The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:
>
> [...]
>
> - The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is
>     indeterminate