# Executing print in standard output causing random assigning of value in array

Tags: c++, c++11, formatting

I'm sorry if this is a silly question.
I have written the following piece of code for coin change problem.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int coinChange(int coins[], int n, int amount)
{
int combinations[amount + 1];
combinations[0] = 1;

int start;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    start = coins[i];
    int coin = coins[i];
    for(int j = start; j < amount + 1; j++)
    {
        if(j >= coin)
        {
            combinations[j] += combinations[j - coin];
        }
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < amount + 1; j++)
        cout << combinations[j] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

return combinations[amount];
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
int coins[] = {1, 2, 5};
int n = sizeof(coins)/sizeof(coins[0]);

int amount = 12;

// cout << "Total combinations: ";
cout << coinChange(coins, n, amount) << endl;

return 0;
}
```

The code works fine and provides me the correct output as shown below.

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 
1 1 2 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10 11 13 
13
```

However, If I uncomment the line `cout << "Total combinations: ";` just above the function calling in the `main` function, the program gives me bizzare outputs.

```
Total combinations: 1 32768 32768 32768 44137 44137 44137 44137 196418491 196418492 -790461916 -790429149 619621115 
1 32768 32769 65536 76906 109673 121043 153810 196539534 196572302 -593922382 -593856847 25698733 
1 32768 32769 65536 76906 109674 153811 186579 196605070 196649208 -593812708 -593703036 25885312 
25885312
```

Is executing `cout` before function calling causing this random outputs? Or is this a problem for my version of compiler?

Comment: I get incorrect output either way. Must be something undefined somewhere.

Comment: Using unitialized values is undefined behavior, random values is one possible outcome see [Is uninitialized local variable the fastest random number generator?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31746063/1708801)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in your `coinChange` function.

```
int combinations[amount + 1]{};
combinations[0] = 1;

int start;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    start = coins[i];
    int coin = coins[i];
    for(int j = start; j < amount + 1; j++)
    {
        if(j >= coin)
        {
            combinations[j] += combinations[j - coin];
        }
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < amount + 1; j++)
        cout << combinations[j] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Now uncomment the line and run. The basic problem is when you create the `combinations` array, you have to initialize the elements to `0`. If you don't, they may be all `0` by a lucky coincidence, but you can't guarantee that.

EDIT : Using empty initializer list to initilize array with zeros as max66 suggested.

Comment: Thanks got it corrected. But Could you tell me why it was working in the first case?

Comment: By dumb luck. In the first case your `combinations` array is sitting on an already "zeroed" block of memory.

Comment: @nakiya I don't think that is a safe assumption, see my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31746063/1708801)

Answer (score 2):

What about initialize (to zero?) `combinations` ?

Something like

```
int combinations[amount + 1] {};
```

Otherwise the initial values of `combinations[i]` are <s>undefined</s> indeterminate, so <s>are</s> is undefined the <s>final values</s> behavior of the program (correction from Shafik Yaghmour; thanks!)

Comment: The initial values [are indeterminate not undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23415662/1708801), using indeterminate values invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour - I didn't know; thanks for the correction.