# Reading from uninitialized memory returns different answers every time

Tags: c++, linux, facebook, linux-kernel, initialization

In [Nicholas Ormrod's talk](https://youtu.be/kPR8h4-qZdk?t=22m17s) at CppCon 2016, he mentioned an insidious bug at Facebook where a single byte had been read from an uninitialized (unwritten-to) page, twice, such that there were cases where the second read returned a (nonzero) value different from the first read's value (zero).

He mentioned they used *jemalloc*, and [I also presume](https://www.quora.com/What-operating-system-do-various-internet-sites-like-Google-Amazon-eBay-Apple-Facebook-Zynga-Twitter-LinkedIin-PayPal-Yahoo-Wikipedia-Groupon-Quora-Netflix-etc-use-on-their-production-servers) they were running on Linux. [jemalloc's manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/jemalloc) says that it always prefers `mmap()` over `sbrk()`.

Now, [jemalloc's only `mmap()` call](https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/blob/e55c3ca26758bcb7f6f1621fd690caa245f16942/src/pages.c) uses the flags `MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS` with the occasional inclusion of `MAP_FIXED`, and in particular it doesn't use `MAP_UNINITIALIZED`. This means that pages are [always zero-initialized](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) when allocated.

Additionally, even [`madvise()` with `MADV_DONTNEED`](https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/blob/e55c3ca26758bcb7f6f1621fd690caa245f16942/src/pages.c#L265) will, for anonymous mappings, return ["zero-fill-on-demand pages"](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) for anonymous mappings, which I read as "zero-initialized pages."

My question is: How is it possible that the second read would ever return a nonzero value, causing their bug?

Comment: To paraphrase the video: the bug Nicholas describes happens when a page is conditionally returned to the kernel, so when you read the byte from the page, the kernel says it's uninitialized memory, so it can return `0`. However, in the second read, you *write* instead of read, so the kernel realizes that you actually need the memory and fetches the actual data stored there

Comment: This question does not provide enough context to be able to answer the question. It is lacking a [mcve]. In order to answer this question, answerers would have to watch the video

Comment: @Justin I linked to the video for extra info, but I mentioned all the details of the bug here.

Comment: @Justin They don't write there. What he said was that the first read causes the bypassing of the write, and then the string returns to the caller which will ultimately re-read it with something other than a null-terminator.

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. Kernel has nothing to do with it.

Comment: See [Is uninitialized local variable the fastest random number generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31739792/1708801) in [my answer to that question I reference a C defect report which talks about "wobbly values"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31746063/1708801)

Answer (score 1):

Whatever explanation this guys is providing is completely broken (at least, in the given context). And the code has undefined behavior no matter what.

If `data` points to the chunk which was allocated with at least `size()` + 1 size, the code has undefined behavior because of the race condition (he mentions usage of threads before).

If the size of the `data` is less than that (for example, equal to `size()`) the code has undefined behavior because of out of bounds access (and race condition becomes a moot point).

Comment: It sounds like they're making all kinds of shortcuts at FB, but since guys like Andrei Alexandrescu (CPP Committee) are working on that code, I give them the benefit of the doubt that they know what they're doing despite triggering UB (and he touches on that earlier in the talk as well). So I'm trying to make sense of his explanation and not throw it out the window.

Comment: Also, reading from any uninitialized storage is already undefined behavior in itself.

Comment: @YamMarcovic that is correct, but I do not know if storage is uninitialized since I do not know how the storage was initialized in the first place. I only watched the video from the point in your link. However, sane assumption would be that it was not, so this is the third undef behavior point.