# Difference Between initializing an array

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I have been getting a weird output if I initialize an array using a variable instead of a constant
the two code below produces a different output for me.

```
int x =7;
int arr[x];
```

and

```
int arr[7];
```

the first one generates this output

```
78  9  73  32  6422216  50  42
```

and the 2nd one

```
78  9  73  54  29  50  42
```

I need to use the size of an vector for the array size.
I have tried making the variable constant but it doesn't makes a difference.

edit
using the array here

```
int arr[size];
for(int j=i;j<nums.size();j++)
    arr[j+1]=nums[j];
arr[i]=nums[signs.size()];
for(int j=0;j<nums.size();j++)
    nums[j]=arr[j];
```

Comment: What do you expect the values to be?

Comment: As local (automatic) variables defined in a function: neither is initialised.

Comment: You have not initialized array.

Comment: C or C++? The latter doesn't even have variable-length arrays.

Comment: You are not initialising array, what you see is leftover garbage

Comment: im using c++ and g++ compiler

Comment: Also note that variable length arrays can't be initialized. You can assign values to the array elements using loop of `memset` function. And VLAs are not supported in C++.

Comment: How does the first one even compile on c++? It would have to be a const int

Comment: @Zebrafish the added code suggests it is C++.

Comment: @juanchopanza the 2nd one is correct

Comment: @irrelevent Why is it correct?

Comment: The first loop (in the "edit" code) starts with `i` and the second loop starts at `0`. That will use uninitialized entries in the array unless `i` is 0.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is uninitialized local variable the fastest random number generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31739792/is-uninitialized-local-variable-the-fastest-random-number-generator)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard

Answer (score 1):

In neither of your two cases is the array initialized.

Without an explicit initializer, the contents of an array (or any variable) are **indeterminate**.  You can't predict what those values will be.  And if one of those values happens to be a trap representation, you invoke undefined behavior if you attempt to read that value.

If you want your array to have a particular set of values to start, you need to set those values explicitly, either with an initializer or by assignment.

Comment: Note that you can't initialize VLAs.

Comment: i edited my post im initializing the array in the loop later on

Comment: @irrelevent; That's called assignment, not initialization.

Comment: Are arrays defined in the global namespace zero initalised like all other variables?

Comment: @Zebrafish If defined at file scope or `static`, then yes all array elements are zero initialized.