# What does the value 'Ì' mean in C?

Tags: c, arrays, visual-studio, null

The elements of an uninitialized char array in C all have the value 'Ì' (or -52 as an integer; 0xCC or 204 as char). Is this another type of null character? Or is it just a value that fills in the values of an uninitialized char array?

(In case it makes any difference, I am using visual studio)

Comment: This is a "junk" value. Like any other. Uninitialized array does not have any defined value.

Comment: "Magic" junk values can be useful in debugging builds to help the runtime detect that you are accessing an uninitialized variable or buffer.  But it can also just really be random junk.  Ancient history:  some compilers used to zero-fill buffers and variables for debug builds but not release builds, causing debug to work but release to crash.  Fun!

Comment: The reason they are all the same is because the VS Debug Heap manager initializes all uninitialized variables to "designer junk" for corruption detection.

Comment: Note that in Hex it's 0xCC - a well recognized pattern.

Comment: You are seeing the side-effect of the /RTC compile option, turned on by default for the debug build.  It helps you detect that you are accessing an uninitialized local variable or an unterminated string.  0xcc is also very likely to cause an access violation for an uninitialized pointer or a debugger break if the program ran away.  And it is used to detect buffer overflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When and why will an OS initialise memory to 0xCD, 0xDD, etc. on malloc/free/new/delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370195/when-and-why-will-an-os-initialise-memory-to-0xcd-0xdd-etc-on-malloc-free-new)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uninitialized variables have indeterminate values. They can make the behavior of your program undefined if the value is used to be a trap representation.

Comment: A comment would be appreciated if the answer is addressing something wrong.

Comment: Can char have trap representation?

Comment: @hyde I think the standard is not explicitly forbidding it.

Comment: For further reference on [using uninitialized variables see "Is uninitialized local variable the fastest random number generator?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31746063/1708801)

Comment: @EugeneSh. In [c whether is has a trap representation changes between C99 and C11](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/03/13/indeterminate-undefined) in C++ [unsigned narrow char types do not have trap rep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23415662/1708801)

Comment: @hyde [see my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49078237/what-does-the-value-%c3%8c-mean-in-c#comment85163479_49078254)

Comment: Just as another question, if you were to put: `if (uninitializerArray[0] == 'Ì') ...`, would that be bad form, since 'Ì' is a "junk" value?

Comment: @pickledonk: it would be incorrect. There is no unique "junk" value, and there is no way to tell that memory is uninitialized.