# Default and zero initialization

Tags: c++

```
#include <string>
 
struct T1 { int mem; };
 
struct T2
{
    int mem;
    T2() { } // "mem" is not in the initializer list
};
 
int n; // static non-class, a two-phase initialization is done:
       // 1) zero initialization initializes n to zero
       // 2) default initialization does nothing, leaving n being zero
 
int main()
{
    int n;            // non-class, the value is indeterminate
    std::string s;    // class, calls default ctor, the value is "" (empty string)
    std::string a[2]; // array, default-initializes the elements, the value is {"", ""}
//  int& r;           // error: a reference
//  const int n;      // error: a const non-class
//  const T1 t1;      // error: const class with implicit default ctor
    T1 t1;            // class, calls implicit default ctor
    const T2 t2;      // const class, calls the user-provided default ctor
                      // t2.mem is default-initialized (to indeterminate value)
}
```

Im currently looking at the reference guide, however there a a few things i don't understand.

I have run the above code, for the struct T2, the data member "int mem" is not in the initialiser list. It is said that t2.mem is default-initialized to an indeterminate value.
But when i run this code, t2.mem seems to be zero initialised for me?

Comment: Zero is a possible indeterminate value, using the value invokes undefined behavior, also see [Has C++ standard changed with respect to the use of indeterminate values and undefined behavior in C++14?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23415661/1708801) also relevent [Is uninitialized local variable the fastest random number generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31739792/1708801)

Comment: *But when i run this code, t2.mem seems to be zero initialised for me?* -- It could be 0, 14, -2323, 784, etc.  Why single out 0 as not being possible indeterminate value?  Second, possibly your compiler (in debug mode) initializes the value to 0.  Many compilers will do this, such as Visual Studio.

Comment: Explains why then, im using VS

Comment: I would expect it to be initialized to `0xcccccccc` in debug mode of Visual Studio. Edit: I just tested it in VS2017 and `t1.mem` and `t2.mem` were both initialized to `0xcccccccc` as I expected. This link explains that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/127404/487892

Answer (score 5):

> But when i run this code, t2.mem seems to be zero initialised for me?

No, in both cases (T1, T2), `mem` is not initialized, or initialize by indeterminate value. The explicit declaration of the constructor in this case does not affect the `mem` initialization. If you want to initialize `mem`, you must do it explicitly in the member initializer list:

```
struct T2
{
    int mem;
    T2() : mem(0) { }
};
```

Or through the default member initializer:

`struct T1 { int mem = 0; };`

Or through aggregate initialization of`T1`, which is only takes place if `T1` does not have any user declared constructors.

```
struct T1 { int mem; }

int main() {
    T1 a{}; // aggregate initialization
    assert(a.mem == 0)

    T1 b; // default constructor does not value initialize mem
}
```

If you see that `mem` initialized by `0` in the second case, then this is most likely a feature of the compiler, or you just get lucky with the `0` value. This is not guaranteed by the standard, don't rely on it.

Comment: I dont think you are correct to be honest, t1 and t2 have automatic storage and are initialised to indeterminate values

Comment: Objects t1 and t2 have automatic storage, subobjects inherit the lifetime of the superobject. They too have automatic storage and are default initialized to indeterminate values

Comment: @AskJheeze, to be honest, I did not understand your thought. Yes,  t1 and t2 are initialised to indeterminate values, that's what i wrote. Yes, subobjects inherit the lifetime of the superobject and default initialized to indeterminate values!